# React Native content is not going to the next row

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I am currently facing a styling issue.

**What am I trying to achieve**

I want to display a list of movies.

There should be around two or three movies showed per row (depending on the available space on the device).

If the list gets too long, then the user should be able to scroll vertically.

**Current situation**

The list of movies does not break into the next row.

[See for yourself, the picture describes the issue the best](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8DNgJ.jpg)

**Code that I am using to achieve my goal**

```
                <ScrollView style={styles.moviesContainer} contentContainerStyle={{flexDirection: "row"}}>
                    <Movie></Movie>
                    <Movie></Movie>
                    <Movie></Movie>
                    <Movie></Movie>
                    <Movie></Movie>
                    <Movie></Movie>
                </ScrollView>
```

^ The moviesContainer styling only contains some margins/border.

I hope that someone can help me with this issue, but if there is something unclear, please let me know so I can add it to this question!

Comment: did you try style `flexWrap: 'wrap'` for the parent?

Comment: On the ScrollView you mean? @VahidAl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `flexWrap` and `flexDirection` on the scroll view.

```
<ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.container}>
  <Movie />
  <Movie />
  <Movie />
  <Movie />
  <Movie />
  <Movie />
  <Movie />
</ScrollView>
```

container style

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
    flexDirection: 'row',
  }
});
```

[DEMO](https://snack.expo.io/@lekgwaraj/scrollview-flexwrap)

Answer (score 0):

try this :

## JSX

```
<ScrollView style={styles.container}>
  <Movie></Movie>
  <Movie></Movie>
  <Movie></Movie>
  <Movie></Movie>
  <Movie></Movie>
  <Movie></Movie>
</ScrollView>
```

## Style :

```
container: {
  flex: 1,
  flexDirection: 'column',
},
```

Comment: Hey Mahdi. Thanks for your reaction. I have tried this before, but this does just give me a vertical list. Image: https://imgur.com/a/w8CE6Tr. This is working fine since you can scroll etc. But it should give me more movies per line since I have more space left.